# Calculating RFE for Recursive Feature Elimination

Tags: scikit-learn, rfe

I have a dataframe called "dataset_con_enc".

```
dataset_con_enc.head()
    OFFER_TYPE_PROXY    OPPLINE_PRODUCT_BU  OPPLINE_PRODUCT_FAMILY  OPP_FLAG_LED_BY_PARTNER     OPP_SOURCE          target
0   0   0   8   0   19  2   1   11  137     1   ...     0   0   5   8   13  578     1   100     100                     1
```

....

I try to do Recursive Feature Elimination for feature selection , so :

```
# Load libraries
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
import warnings

# Suppress an annoying but harmless warning
warnings.filterwarnings(action="ignore", module="scipy", message="^internal gelsd")
# Calculating RFE for non-discretised dataset, and graphing the Importance for each feature, per dataset
selector1 = RFECV(LogisticRegression(), step=1, cv=5, n_jobs=-1)
selector1 = selector1.fit(dataset_con_enc.drop('target', axis=1).values, dataset_con_enc['target'].values)
```

But I get an error in the last code line :

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-509-5e50f1655a89> in <module>()
      3 # Calculating RFE for non-discretised dataset, and graphing the Importance for each feature, per dataset
      4 selector1 = RFECV(LogisticRegression(), step=1, cv=5, n_jobs=-1)
----> 5 selector1 = selector1.fit(dataset_con_enc.drop('target', axis=1).values, dataset_con_enc['target'].values)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_selection\rfe.py in fit(self, X, y)
    434         scores = parallel(
    435             func(rfe, self.estimator, X, y, train, test, scorer)
--> 436             for train, test in cv.split(X, y))
    437 
    438         scores = np.sum(scores, axis=0)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
    747         self._aborting = False
    748         if not self._managed_backend:
--> 749             n_jobs = self._initialize_backend()
    750         else:
    751             n_jobs = self._effective_n_jobs()

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in _initialize_backend(self)
    545         try:
    546             n_jobs = self._backend.configure(n_jobs=self.n_jobs, parallel=self,
--> 547                                              **self._backend_args)
    548             if self.timeout is not None and not self._backend.supports_timeout:
    549                 warnings.warn(

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in configure(self, n_jobs, parallel, **backend_args)
    303         if already_forked:
    304             raise ImportError(
--> 305                 '[joblib] Attempting to do parallel computing '
    306                 'without protecting your import on a system that does '
    307                 'not support forking. To use parallel-computing in a '

ImportError: [joblib] Attempting to do parallel computing without protecting your import on a system that does not support forking. To use parallel-computing in a script, you must protect your main loop using "if __name__ == '__main__'". Please see the joblib documentation on Parallel for more information
```

Can you help me to resolve this probleme please?
thank you

Comment: How are you running the above code? I can run the code from the terminal and also from spyder without any error, with my dataset, in both python2 and python3. Try updating the libraries to the latest version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious fix is to put `n_jobs=1`(disabling parallel computations) --- but I am not sure if that is a solution you are looking for.

Comment: Yes , thank you it works